# how to design a mysql database with phone contacts and find if any contact using the same app?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

Lets say i have an app which fetches all phone contacts. Then checks in the database to find any contact is using the same app. If so then add him as a friend. Lets say a user has 1000 contacts and total users in a database are 1 million. In that case it has to check these 1000 contacts against 1 million users ? Is there any other way i can do a fast lookup ?

Comment: "Is there any other way i can do a fast lookup ?" What makes you think it would be slow?

Comment: Make sure you have an index on the column you're checking against.

Comment: Provide your table(s)' DDL and provide a sample on SQLFiddle. That way, posters can help you more easily - but obviously indexes would be a start. checking 1000 contacts against 10^6 shouldn't be very slow.

Comment: I have to check this frequently to see if any of user's friend has joined the app. Also the total number of users and per user phone contacts will increase day by day. so imagine at a given instance 100 users looking for million records against their 1000 contacts. do u think this will do okay ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check each contact against a 1M rows table, and repeat 1000 times. That would be sub optimal.

I would advice to create a temporary table with the 1000 contacts, create and index on the unique_id of each contact, then join the temporary table with your 1M table on which you of couse already have an index on the unique_id. Store the result in another table (for example "contacts_to_add") and delete the temporary one. (MySQL does this automatically when you use the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` sentence)

This should be fairly quick.

Comment: do u mean temp table for each 1000 contacts of user ? isn't table creation is slower than comparisons ?

Comment: Not necesarily for every 1000 contacts, although 1000 contacts is a lot unless you are a social junkie. The important part is that inserting 1000 records in a temporary table is very quick. Joining two tables with indexed columns is fairly quick. Searching a 1M records table using the IN operator is very inneficient.

Answer (score 0):

Databases support indexes to reduce the complexity of the problem that you are describing.  In pseudo-code:

```
find_my_contacts(); # returns 1000 users (by some unique identifier)
SELECT * FROM users_database WHERE unique_identifier IN ('a', 'b', 'c'); # using a list of identifiers returned from above.
```

As long as `unique_identifier` is indexed, this will be 1000 [B-tree lookups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) in [logarithmic time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_time#Logarithmic_time).  It is quite efficient, and scales well with the number of users added to the system.